# Unable to search with FirstOrDefault Method

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, asp.net-web-api

We need a simple Web-API to fetch data from a sql server. 
It should run on an IIS due to our company policy.

I wasn't able to find an finished (free) solution. Therefore I came to this solution while googling -> 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nMGlaiNBbNU

Nearly all is working fine. I can fetch a full list from my table.

The only thing I can't fix is. It's not possible to get only one data set via 
http://localhost:12345/api/GHServer/searchstring

`SEARCHSTRING` should be a valid server name in my table. But instead of a single data set I always get a full list again. What could be the reason for this?

Here my controller.cs

```
namespace GHServerDataAPI.Controllers
{
    public class GHServerController : ApiController
    {

        public View_GHServerExportWithNet Get(String Server)
        {
            using (GHServerDevEntities entities = new GHServerDevEntities())
            {
                return entities.View_GHServerExportWithNet
                               .FirstOrDefault(S => S.Server == Server);
            }
        }


        public IEnumerable<View_GHServerExportWithNet> Get()
        {
            using(GHServerDevEntities entities = new GHServerDevEntities())
            {
                return entities.View_GHServerExportWithNet.ToList();
            }
        }
     }
}
```

`IEnumerable<View_GHServerExportWithNet> Get()` -> works as expected.

`public View_GHServerExportWithNet Get(String Server)` -> doesn't work any way or is unable to find any matches although I'm sure I deliver a valid search string.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Can you add the exception you are seeing or the expected vs actual results?

Answer (score 1):

If you debug on Visual Studio there is a diagnostic tool available for you. From there you can see ADO action. That is in essence you will see the translation of your entity framework to SQL queries.  Grab the generated query and run it against your SQL server.

If you don't see the diagnostic tools

Debug --> Windows --> Show Diagnostic Tools

Additionally, I don't think you are reaching your method that accepts a string parameter. Put a breakpoint there and I'm almost sure you'll not hit it.

If that's the case, try

```
[Route("{server}"]
public View_GHServerExportWithNet GetByName(string server) { ... }
```

Comment: Agree - If the method is returning the whole list, then you're not hitting the overload you expect

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not able to hit that route.

Add the below two attributes to your method

```
[Route("GHServer/{Server}")]
[HttpGet]
public View_GHServerExportWithNet Get(String Server)
```

Enable Attribute routing in WebAPIConfig as mentioned below:

```
public static class WebApiConfig 
{
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) 
{ 
     // Web API routes 
     config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
     // Other Web API configuration not shown.
}
}
```

If that doesn't work, also please try comparing the server string to "ToUpper()" as below:

```
return entities.View_GHServerExportWithNet.FirstOrDefault(S => 
S.Server.Trim().ToUpper() == Server);
```

Comment: OK, I've tried this. but the result ist the same. 
I'm sorry but some one disallowed me to answer here in a proper way. Because I'm producing "Spam"... grrrrr! Yes I'm a beginner in C#. Anyone will start on bottom...
If any one here would be a dev geek we do not need this plattform...

Comment: I watched that video.. can you please try this in Get method.
                return entities.View_GHServerExportWithNet.ToList()
                               .FirstOrDefault(S => S.Server == Server);.         also could you please show the code for this class file View_GHServerExportWithNet